# Referencing between CodeDomObjects and Text

Tags: codedom

I am writing a CodeGenerator. The string output is later on mixed with user code.
In order to be able to make changes to my generated code after the user edits the file, I have to make sure my generated parts are not editable.

I am currently not sure how to achieve this behaviour..
If I would be able to track which line correlates to which CodeDomObject and vice versa I could tell my TextEditor to mark Lines as read only.

But at this Point I have two problems.

- I don't know how to keep track.
- I am not sure if my solution ( which I am not able to implement... ) is
  clean. There would be a lot of overhead, because I have to find out
  which object is generated and which not. I could do so by comparing a
  generated CodeDomTree with the actual Tree and marking the diffs as
  UserObjects.

Comment: Maybe you could use `#region`s for that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this solution is practical in your environment but this is handled using [`partial`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/wa80x488.aspx) classes where required in Visual Studio.

An example would be Windows Forms where the visual designer is responsible for creating source code to reproduce the form at runtime but the developer is expected to add event handling code to the class.

By having the developer's code in a separate source file it doesn't get overwritten when changes are made in the designer.

Of course, this won't help you if you need to have a single source file for your class.